# Pass object by reference to nested lit-element

Tags: lit-element

There are few nested elements and a main state object. I see that there is no way pass an object by reference like at Angular for example to be available at the bottom. I see that it is possible to work through the global environment. But it is not a clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass the actual object as a property then you need to use the "dot notation" of lit-html.

```
<my-el .data=${dataObject}></my-el>
```

this is basically the same as doing

```
document.querySelector('my-el').data = dataObject;
```

Comment: I see. .data works only inside lit-component. Outside use ocument.querySelector('my-el').data . Is it possible by an attribute declaratively outside the lit-component.

Comment: attributes work everywhere like this `<my-el my-attribute="test-string"></my-el>`

Comment: In this case, it thee string, object is required.

Comment: passing an object as a string is not really advised - it can work if you pass a stringified json and then parse the json in the component... with LitElement if you use "type: Object"  it will automatically convert it https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#conversion-type

Comment: Yes, I understand. It is the main feature of the web component - no data leack. But right now I need to pass an object through.